# bake cakephp configure console profile

Tags: bash, cakephp, mamp, .profile, cakephp-bake

i've just installed **CakePHP** and I'm pretty new with Mac,Shells and Terminal..
Cakephp is now running correctly and  as stated by my tutorial (Beginning-Cakephp-from novice to professional) i'm now trying to **configure console profile to run Bake** (i'm on MAMP also).
I typed in the Terminal:

```
vi .profile
```

then I inserted an alias:

```
alias cake="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/luca/cake/cake/console/cake.php"
```

If I go trying for  $ cake bake now i receive the message:

```
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php: Permission denied
```

what's wrong?

thanks
Luca

P.S I saw few other tutorial that used to edit .profile with exporting a path..what's the difference and how does it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can bake actually if I navigate to mydir/cake/console, and then run the command

```
$ ./cake bake
```